# 'An avalanche of mail'? - it should be 'mails', shouldn't it?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, singular

I came across this example on WordWeb while going through the meaning of the word '[avalanche](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/AVALANCHE)'.

> *the program brought an avalanche of mail* (Just like *"a group of <del>man</del> men").*

I'm quite sure it should be *mails.* Kindly confirm.

Comment: Not to be confused with *[an avalanche of males](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dl5aZJBLAu1E%26feature%3Dkp&ei=XfazU_3fJcy2yATEh4LYDw&usg=AFQjCNE9i_5bhSy0kuSMbNdj35RqSB7jtw&sig2=9_6ZboG-gYNh40rU-_qfaA)*, which is correctly pluralized.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName lol. I certainly got confused but with *emails*. :) I was just concerned about putting 'plural'. J.R. clarified it.

Comment: The count noun for *mail* is *letter*. The count noun for *email* is *email*. So it could be *an avalanche of emails* or *an avalanche of letters* of *an avalanche of email*, but not *an avalanche of mail*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely not.

*Mail* is a uncountable noun, as in: "There is a lot of mail in that mailbag."

Therefore, it would be an avalanche of *mail* (but an avalanche of *letters*).

We would say, "Would you please take this *mail* down to the mailbox?" even if there were three pieces of mail to take.

Comment: Ah, I thought it *mails* i.e. *emails.* I lead the content department in an IT company. Recently we had an event and we really got an avalanche of emails. That's the fact!

Comment: In this context either _email_ or _emails_ would be fine.  But definitely not _mails_.

Comment: @MarkPattison Since the *postal service* is almost on the edge of its extinction, *You mail me the documents* is taken as emailing the documents. That's what I thought first. You get a lot of emails after a successful event/program. In addition, we recently went through this pleasing experience so I was driven away a bit! :)

Comment: @MarkPattison But I disagree using *email* in this context. Though *email* could be a mass noun, but when it follows *an avalanche*, it *should be* counted as a 'countable noun' i.e. emails.

Comment: Maulik - I'm inclined to agree with @MarkP in this case. The word _emails_ is sometimes used to mean _email messages_, so "an avalanche of emails" sounds okay to me, even though "an avalanche of mails" does not. That said, _email_ can refer to everything in the inbox, not just individual messages, so "an avalanche of email" sounds okay as well. I don't think both words always function the same way. Of course, _email_ is a much newer word than _mail_, so the dust probably hasn't fully settled on this issue yet.

Comment: @MaulikV Why should *an avalanche of X* require that X be a count noun? What is a literal avalanche but an avalanche *of snow* (mass noun). Either a mass noun or count noun is fine here; *email* can be used as either, but *mail*, even when referring to email, can only be a mass noun.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus "Either a mass noun or count noun is fine here; email can be used as either, but mail, even when referring to email, can only be a mass noun." So you're saying that it's fine to say "He sent me three emails yesterday" but not "He sent me three electronic mails yesterday"? That doesn't make sense. For snail mail, I agree, since a single item of that kind of mail is referred to as a letter, rather than "a mail".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I not aware of anyone who refers to "an email" as "an electronic mail". But if they did then it would be OK for them to say "three electronic mails". If the etymology went "mail" (mass noun) -> "electronic mail" (mass noun) -> "email" (mass noun) -> "email" (both mass noun and count noun meaning "email message"), then there's no "electronic mail" (count noun). More immediately, since *nobody calls it electronic mail* there's not even really any "electronic mail" (mass noun) ;-)

Comment: I believe the "count noun" version of email is "message(s)".

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus I meant either it should be a count noun or a mass noun but not a singular term for sure.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Exactly. We often heard 'send me an email' and 'I'm off of the Internet. God knows my inbox must be flooded with emails.* And as I said, today, when postcards are not in practice, send me mail does refer to send me an email.

Comment: @MaulikV - That's twice now you've referred to the demise of the post office. I wouldn't say that "send me mail" means "send me an email" by default. Maybe I'm too set in my ways, but I still say "email" when I mean _email_. Sometimes I'll use the term _snail mail_ when I want to make it clear that I won't be sending something electronically.

Comment: @MaulikV Mass nouns always take the singular form in English. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus - Let's not say "always". As that Wiki link says, _Some mass nouns can be used in English in the plural to mean "more than one instance (or example) of a certain sort of entity"_